# How to scroll to a specific element in selenium?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, scroll, phpunit

I am trying to fill a field with some text but it is not visible on the screen and it requires scrolling to be visible.

I am using the moveto funcion

```
$this->webdriver->moveto($this->element);
```

But it gives me the following error

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (373.5, 15): [object HTMLInputElement]
```

I can see alot of posts on stackoverflow for this error but I did not find any one specific to php selenium testing.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **moveToElement** functionality. It worked for me.

FYR :- https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/master/lib/interactions/WebDriverActions.php#L164

Comment: moveToElement function is not avialble

Comment: So you need to downgrade your version and check is it available or not. This is the functionality we use to do this operation.

Comment: I have this `"phpunit/phpunit": "dev-only-repeat-failed as 4.8.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": "dev-better-exception-handling as 1.4.2",`. to which version should I downgrade?

Comment: v4.8.0 check this also I think you can do thins also https://www.360logica.com/blog/multiple-ways-to-scroll-a-page-using-selenium-webdriver/